# CallKit doesn't block numbers from array

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, callkit, callblocking

I create numbers array from CNContact in singleton. But when I reload my CallKit extensions CallKit doesn't block number that I blocked before. Number length is 11 characters. Array isn't null. After reload CallKit Extension there is no error.

```
static let shared = BlockNumbersManager()
    private init() { }
    open var blockNumbers: [CXCallDirectoryPhoneNumber] = []
open func getIntegerBlockNumbers() -> [CXCallDirectoryPhoneNumber] {
        return blockNumbers
    }



private func addBlockingPhoneNumbers(to context: CXCallDirectoryExtensionContext) throws {
        let phoneNumbers: [CXCallDirectoryPhoneNumber] = BlockNumbersManager.shared.getIntegerBlockNumbers() // TODO: add numbers for block dynamically.
        for phoneNumber in phoneNumbers {
            context.addBlockingEntry(withNextSequentialPhoneNumber: phoneNumber)
        }
    }
```

What have I missed?

Comment: What do you mean "CallKit doesn't block number that I blocked before"?  Before when?  You must return the complete set of numbers that you want to block each time your extension is loaded

Comment: I have written not correct. Sorry. CallKit doesn't block number from block array that I added before.

Comment: @SeverynKatolyk did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: @Brittany Not yet. I've frizzed that project for the present.

Answer (score 3):

While @Stuart 's answer makes quite good points, I'd like to add some tips from my side, after I spent over 1 hour to figure out why my Call Directory extension did not work...

1. The phone number format: check if you've added the country code. In my case I tested with Australian mobile number like 0412345678, so it should be either 61412345678, or +61412345678. Yes both worked for me.
2. Mind the iOS cache! What you've written in your Call Directory extension does not get executed/called each time you restart or run your app. i.e. You think you've appended some new phone numbers in the blocking array but iOS actually may not load it as you expected. The trick is to toggle your app's option in Settings -> Phone -> Call Blocking & Identification.
3. You may want to call **CXCallDirectoryManager.reloadExtension** in your main app when a reload is needed to invalidate the iOS cache.

Answer (score 2):

while parsing an array to blocking function you should note 5 points

1. Check that E**xtension is enabled** in settings (give **permission** to your app extention)
2. must include **country code**
3. Array must be in ascending order.
   **while you sort your array it should be in integer or any numeric form (do not sort array in String form)**
4. In Array there should not be any **duplicate numbers**
5. there should be proper numbers ( you should not block 123 like this do not wrong number )

Answer (score 1):

Currently in iOS 10.x, every time your Call Directory extension runs it must provide a *complete* set of phone numbers to either block or identify with a label. In other words, if it runs once and adds blocked phone numbers `[A, B, C]`, and you wish to also block phone number `D`, then the next time the extension is run it must provide the complete list `[A, B, C, D]`.

In iOS 11, some new APIs have been added which allow the extension to provide data *incrementally* whenever possible. For instance, if the extension has already run once and added blocked phone numbers `[A, B, C]`, and you wish to also block phone number `D`, then the next time the extension is run it may first check if the system allows incremental loading, and if it does then it may add blocked numbers `[D]` and the full list of blocked numbers will become `[A, B, C, D]`.

Note that when using the new iOS 11 incremental loading APIs, your extension must always check whether incremental loading is currently allowed. The system may occasionally need to reload the *complete* list of phone numbers and your extension must remain able to provide the complete list.

See the documentation for these new APIs at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/callkit/cxcalldirectoryextensioncontext

In addition, you may view the 'Call Directory Extension' iOS extension template in Xcode 9 which has been updated to demonstrate the new incremental loading APIs:

[image: Xcode Call Directory Extension target template screenshot]

Comment: Hi. It's useful information but my problem is that when I hardcode my number like [3809...] than call kit block it but when I return number for CNContact than it doesn't block. Besides array that I return isn't nil. Every time I reload extension with full stack of numbers.

Comment: Are you saying that if you include a phone number that you retrieve from a CNContact instance in your list of phone numbers provided to the CallKit API, then that phone number is not blocked? If so, is that phone number a fully-qualified, international number, including the country code? Be sure to still include the country code, even when retrieving phone numbers from contact objects.

Comment: Yes You understand correctly and yes number is full. 12 digits in number. Fro example 38-093-444-44-44.

Comment: I think you'll need to either post a more complete code example to determine what the issue is, or file a bug with Apple's [Bug Report](https://bugreport.apple.com) (Radar) system detailing the issue and including your example code there.

Answer (score 1):

Check each phone number in your contact list, if any number without country code are listed then it will not added to blocking list, you must have to provide Country code + Number

Answer (score 0):

**It blocks the array. There are several limitations:-**

**I followed all these steps and its working flawless.**

1. When you install app which has extension make sure you enable your extension from Setting -> Phone -> Call Blocking & Identifications , turn on the switch for your extension.
2. Verify the phone number, just to make sure you don't enter invalid numbers , because a single wrong number will void the number blocking.Use PhoneNumberKit its a great library.
   https://github.com/marmelroy/PhoneNumberKit
3. Remember sorting array doesn't work on Array of string. Make sure u convert array string to Int64.

> ```
> let arrayInt64 = decodedItems.map { str in
>     if let intValue = Int64(str){
>        return intValue
>     }else{
>        return 0
>     }
> }
> ```

4. Make sure u remove the duplicates before passing to context.addBlockingEntry

> ```
> import Algorithms
> let numbers = [1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1]  
> print(numbers.uniqued()) // prints [1, 2, 3]
> ```

OR

> ```
> var uniqueArray : [Int64] = []
> for element in arrayInt64{
>     if !uniqueArray.contains(element){
>         uniqueArray.append(element)
>     }
> }
> ```

5. Most Important sort the array in ascending order.

> ```
> uniqueArray.sorted(by: <)
> ```